# Accessing the class name of the page being edited

Tags: silverstripe

How can I output the classname of the page being edited in the admin interface?

I'm overriding the file CMSMain_Content.ss to add this:

```
  <a href="http://example.com/settings/$ClassName">
      Help
  </a>
```

However, unlike front-end templates the $ClassName variable is not present in admin pages.

How can i output the object's classname or pagetype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in CMSMain, you can use `$CurrentPage.ClassName` instead.

Comment: if i'm in CMSMain for a model admin page, is there an equivelent to that to tell me which model admin i'm in? @EagleEye

Comment: Not sure about this, but I don't think you're in CMSMain, but just in ModelAdmin. In ModelAdmin you could use `$this->modelClass` to get the classname of the current ModelAdmin tab.